# Problems with MongoID and one to many relations

Tags: ruby, mongoid, one-to-many, database-relations

I encountered the following problem with MongoID.
I've created two models which related by one to many.

```
require 'mongoid'

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :configs

  field :login, :type => String, unique: true
  field :password, :type => String
  field :email, :type => String
end

class Config
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user

  field :links, :type => Array
  field :root, :type => Array
  field :objects, :type => Array
  field :categories, :type => Array
end
```

After that I've created new `User` instance:

```
user = User.new
user.login = "login1"
user.password = "password1"
user.email = "email1"
user.save
```

But I saw the following output:

```
/home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:550:in `criteria': undefined method `where' for RbConfig:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/metadata.rb:143:in `criteria'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/referenced/many.rb:20:in `build'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:43:in `create_relation'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `build'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:101:in `block (4 levels) in getter'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:125:in `_loading'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:100:in `block (3 levels) in getter'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:84:in `_building'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in getter'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/validations.rb:51:in `read_attribute_for_validation'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `block in validate'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_before_1'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__852778899__validate__1039643020__callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:43:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:212:in `run_validations!'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__852778899__validation__1039643020__callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:43:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/validations.rb:75:in `valid?'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:187:in `invalid?'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:23:in `block in prepare'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `tap'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `prepare'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:26:in `persist'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:49:in `insert'
    from /home/scepion1d/Workspace/RubyMine/dana-x/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.6/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:154:in `upsert'
    from parser/parsing_starter.rb:47:in `<main>'
```

If I remove the lines with "has_many" and "belongs_to" then the program will work correctly.
Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's some kind of collision with your `Config` class and one that might already be defined. Try changing the name of the model to something like `UserConfig`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a wrapper module to namespace your classes:

```
module MyApp
   class Config 
      ...
   end

   class User
      ...
   end
end
```